# Get date and time out of julian string

Tags: python, datetime, time, julian-date

i have a list of julian date:
42304.90625

I startet like this:

```
jDate=42304.90625  
jDate=jDate[0:5] 
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(jDate, '%y%j').date()
```

How can i extract the time?
Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: This might help https://pypi.org/project/julian/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your use of `%j` in the conversion I take it you mean a mainframe "Julian" date of the form YYDDD. Start by splitting the value into an integer part and a fractional part:

```
>>> date, time = divmod(jDate, 1.0)
>>> date
42304.0
>>> time
0.90625
```

Using `divmod()` like this doesn't work on negative numbers, but a Julian date is never negative. Now convert the date to a string. A correct way to do that is:

```
date = str(int(date))
```

Doing this: `jDate=jDate[0:5]` *doesn't work* because `jDate` is a float. (The title of your posting says it's a string but your code says it's a float.)

Next convert the fractional day into seconds:

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(days=time)
datetime.timedelta(0, 78300)
```

and add the two together:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%y%j') + datetime.timedelta(days=0.90625)
datetime.datetime(2042, 10, 31, 21, 45)
```